# Custom Labels in Experience Builder

Tags: experience-cloud, customlabel, experience-builder-page

I've been searching for a while alternative ways to reference a label in this standard login form in the Experience builder of Experience Cloud (Communities).

It seems any of these ways are working:

- {!Label.CLIENTELLING_LOGIN_USER}
- {$!Label.CLIENTELLING_LOGIN_USER}

I've tried to change it to preview to see if it works but i got the same blank fields.

Got any idea how this could work?

Thank you!

[image: Login form Labels in experience builder]

Comment: Should you not be using [multilingual site](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_multilingual_overview.htm&type=5) capabilities? When the user is about to log in, since they are not yet logged in Salesforce won't know what language is associated with their User...?

Comment: Thank you Phil, you are right. Sorry i'm new to Experience cloud :) . But anyways, are custom labels not working in experience builder then?

Comment: I think they do work in most cases, but here I'd argue that Salesforce doesn't know what language to select since there's no logged in contextual user (yet)...